# Removing PAGELATCH with randomized ID instead of GUID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, sql-server-2019

We have two tables which receive 1 million+ insertions per minute. This table is heavily indexed, which also can’t be removed to support business requirements. Due to such high volume of insertions, we are seeing PAGELATCH_EX and PAGELATCH_SH. These locks further slowdown insertions.

A commonly accepted solution is to change the identity column to GUID so that insertions are written on random page every time. We can do this but changing IDs will trigger a need for the development cycle of migration scripts so that existing production data can be changed.

I tried another approach which seems to be working well in our load tests. Instead of changing to GUID, We are now generating IDs in a randomized pattern using following logic

```
SELECT @ModValue = (DATEPART(NANOSECOND, GETDATE()) % 14);
INSERT xxx(id)
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Sequence * (@ModValue + IIF(@ModValue IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6), 100000000000,-100000000000))
```

It has eliminated PAGELATCH_EX and PAGELATCH_SH locks and our insertions are quite fast now. I also think GUID as PK of such a critical table is less efficient then a bigint ID column.

However, some of team members are sceptical on this as IDs with negative values that too generated on random basis is not a common solution. Also, there is argument that support team may struggle due to large negative IDs. A common habit of writing select * from table order by 1 will need to be changed.

I am wondering what the community’s take on this solution. If you could please point any disadvantage of approach suggested, that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Using `datepart` and `nanonsecond` with `getdate()` doesn't seem an obvious combination to me as getdate() returns a datetime not datetime2.  It also isn't obvious to me that this approach ensures uniqueness and that you won't get duplicates. Assuming this is the case then the fact that it can generate -ve integers should be irrelevant The `ORDER BY 1` "issue" would also apply to the Guid. But presumably they are doing that as they want to order by insertion order? So how will you cater for that need?

Comment: You could also look at `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY` but I did get much better results from simply getting rid of the sequential key when I had a similar issue

Comment: If they're worried about negative values, then shift all your IDs by, say, 200 billion. Problem solved? A `BIGINT` is large enough to support many partitions. The linear order is still borked, but the proper solution there is to add the timestamp as its own column and order on that. Counting on IDs to be temporally ordered is a bad pattern even if they happen to be generated in sequential order now, since this is a burdensome restriction. If the temporal order of rows is of such importance, the time deserves to be surfaced separately.

Comment: As an aside, counting on `SELECT * ORDER BY 1` to work is even worse than relying on IDs to be sequential, since this is also assuming the "first" column is that ID (I put "first" in quotes because while the physical order is real, the engine by and large doesn't care, so relying on that rather than names is a bad idea). If you have a whole culture of people accustomed to such assumptions tying down the design, I'd suggest that's what views are there to overcome. They can even get a view where the time column is now the first one, which means their ad-hoc selects won't break.

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith Thanks for pointing out the getdate() issue. I have changed getdate() to SYSDATETIME(). We tried OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY but it did not do anything for us. It simply changed lock, but performance was same.

About uniqueness, I am hoping that window created by given logic is large enough to cater our load for many years. The logic given above will create 14 windows. Every window should be able to hold one hundred billion rows. This much of range should be good enough.

Comment: Right now we are implementing similar solution but with less shuffling. We have N workers(kubernetes pods) each of it request range of 10k from sequence and then uses it whenever needed. Effectively that shuffles IDs only within last seconds-minutes(if observing createdAt in inserted rows) + no negative IDs. That leads to N hot pages somewhere at the "end" of a table(still no pagelatches). As our tests showed "optimize for sequencial key" reduces performance degradation up to 30% starting from 64+ workers(not yet checked in production), it is used on index that has CreatedAt as first column.

Comment: So you are creating N sequences? If your pods are getting created on fly, then would you be creating sequnces dynamically as well? I am using -ve IDs so that there is next to none chances of overlapping.

Comment: No no. We have 1 sequence per table (still if it is bigint - it can be shared across multiple tables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, some of team members are skeptical on this as IDs with negative values that too generated on random basis is not a common solution

You have an uncommon problem, and so uncommon solutions might need to be entertained.

> Also, there is argument that support team may struggle due to large negative IDs. A common habit of writing select * from table order by 1 will need to be changed.

Sure. The system as it exists now has a high (but not perfect) correlation between IDs and time. That is, in general a higher ID for a row means that it was created after one with a lower ID. So it's convenient to order by IDs as a stand-in for ordering by time. If that's something that they need to do (i.e. order the data by time), give them a way to do that in the new proposal. Conversely, play out the hypothetical scenario where you're explaining to your CTO why you didn't fix performance on this table for your end users. Would "so that our support personnel don't have to change the way they do things" be an acceptable answer? I know that it wouldn't be for me but maybe the needs of support outweigh the needs of end users in your system. Only you (and your CTO) can answer that question.